# Azure Deployment Visual Studio Online Could Not Find Part of Parth

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy my project from VS Online, but I am getting this error. It appears that the software is looking for my cloud project in the wrong location. How do I change the location of where Visual Studio Online is looking for my cloud project? It definitely exists on the server.

[image]

```
Built $/ConnexForQuickBooks/Solutions/ConnexForQuickBooks/ConnexForQuickBooks.sln for target(s) Azure\CloudService1:Publish.
Built C:\a\src\ConnexForQuickBooks\..\..\Azure\CloudService1\CloudService1.ccproj.metaproj for target(s) Publish.
C:\a\src\ConnexForQuickBooks\..\..\Azure\CloudService1\CloudService1.ccproj.metaproj: Error reading project file "..\..\Azure\CloudService1\CloudService1.ccproj": Could not find a part of the path 'C:\a\Azure\CloudService1\CloudService1.ccproj'.
Run optional script after MSBuild
```

Comment: Hi,I figured it out. I backed up my code and I deleted the repo on Visual Studio Online. I disconnected my azure cloud service from Visual Studio. I created a new repo and merged in my code. I reconnected Visual Studio Online and Azure.